Is there an algorithm trick to solve bracket placement permutations in boolean expressions?
The problem (original found here) is to be given a random string of t's and f's (standing for boolean true/false) separated by one of & | ^ e.g. "T&F|F^T&T^F" and write a function to return the number of unique bracket placements (where total # of bracket pairs = # of t/f's - 1) for which the overall expression will evaluate to true. (T&((F^T)|(T&F))) is true.
My code returns the correct answer, but not in the allotted time (for very long input strings). I'm looking for a hint as to whether I need to understand an algorithm trick that drastically reduces iterations/recursions, or my code just isn't efficient enough.
My algorithm essentially iterates through every pairing, but after reducing any given tf pair to a single new value, it checks the resulting string of char/bracket placement against a lookup table to see if that pattern has been reached previously, and continues without recursing if it has.
For instance if the input is T T F T F F T: If we're on a permutation where the first pair is (T T)F T F F T, and the second pair is (T T)F T(F F)T, well, eventually we'll have a permutation whose first pair is T T F T(F F)T and whose second is (T T)F T(F F)T, at which point the table will show this path to have already been traversed and will proceed to the next permutation.
I also perform a check each time a tf string is reduced e.g. (T&F)^F|T&T --> F^F|T&T to make sure there is at least one T left, since F^F|F&F needs no more recursion.
I feel like there must be a way to reduce the amount of traversal beyond what I've done.
(CodeWars discussion here)
//  C++.   The input will be given as two strings, e.g. "ttfftf","&&^|^"

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using pairVec = vector<pair<string,char>>;

unordered_map<string, bool> usedPatMap{};

inline char tOrF(char c1, char c2, char op){
    if(c1=='f') {
        if(c2=='f') return 'f';
        else { // c2=='t'
            if(op=='&') return 'f';
            return 't';
        }
    }
    else { //c1=='t'
        if(c2=='f') {
            if(op=='&') return 'f';
            return 't';
        }
        else { // c2=='t'
            if(op=='^') return 'f';
            return 't';
        }
    }
  }

void traverse(pairVec& tfs, string ops, int64_t& ct) {
    for(int i = 0; i + 1 < tfs.size(); ++i) {
      char tf = tOrF(tfs[i].second, tfs[i+1].second, ops[i]);
      string newBracePat = "(" + tfs[i].first + tfs[i+1].first + ")";
      pairVec tfs2 = tfs;
      string ops2 = ops;
      auto p = tfs2.erase(tfs2.begin() + i, tfs2.begin() + 2 + i);
      tfs2.insert(p,make_pair(newBracePat,tf));
      
      if(find_if(tfs2.begin(), tfs2.end(),
            [](auto x){ return x.second=='t';})==tfs2.end()) continue;

      string checkStr;
      for(auto pr:tfs2) checkStr.append(pr.first);
      if(!usedPatMap[checkStr]) usedPatMap[checkStr] = true;
      else continue;
      
      ops2.erase(ops2.begin()+i);
      if(ops2.empty()) {
        if(tfs2[0].second=='t') ++ct;
        return; }
      traverse(tfs2, ops2, ct);
    }
   }

int64_t solve(const string &s, const string &ops) {
  
    if(s.length() < 2 || ops.length()!=s.length() - 1) return 0;
    int64_t ct = 0;

    string s2 = s, ops2 = ops;
  pairVec v(s2.length(),{"x",'t'});
  for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); ++i) if(s2[i]=='f') v[i].second = 'f';
  traverse(v, ops2, ct);
  return ct;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  cout<<solve("ttftfftftf","|&^&&||^&");
}


Great! The second sentence in the problem description there cleared things up quite a bit. Perhaps you should have included it? "t,f will stand for true, false and ..."

Note the given code left out the main function and the required headers. This isn't a bug hunt so a [mre] isn't mandatory, but they generally help and you are so close to having one that you might as well finish the job.

BTW, your code fails on basic tests: https://godbolt.org/z/KPExMvfha so there is not point considering performance (global state may be part of problem).

After fixing minor problem in your code: https://godbolt.org/z/99Mf8o8E9 it fails on single simple test case.

@user4581301, the code is from CodeWars; the headers are all provided and the site calls the user's function, so no main() is involved on my end.

@MarekR, I don't know how that can be the case: my code passes CodeWars tests for patterns that yield hundreds or thousands of True answers. It times out for longer strings... Amending the code to handle "t" as an input doesn't fix the timeout issue...

@MarekR, I added a simple line so that "t" yields 1 and all of the Godbolt tests now pass. But this doesn't fix the CodeWars problem, as I think the problem always passes a string of at least two chars with an operator between.

That generally doesn't matter as you are here now, and people here may need to run your code to experiment with it and test it. Are you going to accept answers from folk who haven't tested what they wrote? If your answer is yes, all I can say is "YOU FOOL!"

I added main() and headers to the code. However, I know that my algorithm works... I am looking for someone who can tell me if there is a more clever algorithm to reduce iterations, because my code takes ≈10 seconds to process a string of 14 t/f's, the allotted time is 12 seconds, and I'm sure the site is feeding strings longer than 14.

Algorithm works, but you think it can work better. That sounds like a potential candidate for Code Review. Best to make sure with a read-through of their asking questions help pages, particularly What topics can I ask about here?

Did you ask this question on the CodeWars forums?

This is my code which passes on CodeWars.  It is just brutal force with caching results. I didn't analyzed your code, but looks like you are not doing smart caching of results.

Every string with "unique bracket placement" corresponds to a binary tree. Every root operation you pick divides the input string into two parts that again can be assembled into a tree. The neat part is that you can calculate the counts for both subtrees separately and then combine the results of both parts.

@MarekR, thanks. I'm not going to look at your code yet, and see if I can figure out first what you mean by the smart caching. I assumed something like that was in play, but as of yet I haven't been able to get my mind around how that works.

@Botje, thanks, I will see if I can wrap my head around what you're saying. I've only toyed with programming on a hobby basis off and on for about 4 years, so a lot of concepts are still new to me.

And of course in the very abstract you do not have to construct the trees at all, you can just talk about the number of results for a given segment of the input.

"The problem (click to see)" - No. Don't "click to see", SO questions should be entirely self contained. The question should include "the problem" (whatever it is), not hide it behind a link to an external site (that may rot in the future).

@Eljay I did, but no one was answering and I was getting antsy to progress!

@JesperJuhl The problem is explained in my post, but someone advised that I include the link to the original.

Excellent!  Please update the question with a link to the discussion on the forum over there, so we can see that conversation as well.

Well, I thought that I discovered a way of checking the count total of subtrees, and simply returning the count instead of traversing the subtree, but even so, my code is very slow.
So, @MarekR, I looked at your code after all. Can you explain to me what is happening in the mergeOps() method? I don't know how I could have figured out to perform the multiplications and additions of positives/negatives that are happening there...

@MarekR, I managed to make sense of what was going on in your code. A very enlightening problem for me, so thanks for your help.

From a brief look at your code I notice that you actually construct strings with the parentheses inserted at different places. This certainly represents a lot of manipulation that actually is not necessary.
No string manipulation is needed. It should suffice to calculate the results for substrings of your input, and collect for each the number of false-results and the number of true-results. If you start with the smallest substrings, having just one f or t value, then it is trivial. Then you can rely on those results to calculate the counts for substrings which have two operands and one operator. This gives a new layer of results. For the next layers you need to also consider the choice of the operator you will have at the top (with a left and right side operand of smaller sizes, for which you already have the counts).
This is a description of a bottom-up dynamic programming solution.
I provide here C style code, using plain arrays. For C++ it would be good to use vectors instead as you were doing:
int64_t solve(const std::string &s, const std::string &ops)
{
    size_t n = s.length();
    int64_t dp[n][n][2]; // Dynamic programming tabulation
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int64_t isTrue = (s[i] == 't');
        dp[0][i][0] = 1 - isTrue;
        dp[0][i][1] = isTrue;
    }
    int64_t *counters = dp[0][0];
    for (size_t opCount = 1; opCount < n; opCount++) {
        for (size_t start = 0; start + opCount < n; start++) {
            counters = dp[opCount][start];
            counters[0] = counters[1] = 0;
            for (size_t leftOpCount = 0; leftOpCount < opCount; leftOpCount++) {
                int64_t *left = dp[leftOpCount][start];
                int64_t *right = dp[opCount - 1 - leftOpCount][start + leftOpCount + 1]; 
                int64_t ff = left[0] * right[0];
                int64_t ft = left[0] * right[1] + left[1] * right[0];
                int64_t tt = left[1] * right[1];
                char op = ops[start + leftOpCount];
                if (op == '&') {
                    counters[0] += ff + ft;
                    counters[1] += tt;
                } else if (op == '|') {
                    counters[0] += ff;
                    counters[1] += tt + ft;
                } else {
                    counters[0] += ff + tt;
                    counters[1] += ft;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return counters[1];
}

The first dimension of dp represents the number of operators in the considered expression. The second dimension has the start index in s where this sub-expression starts. The third dimension has just two entries: one for the false-counts and one for the true-counts.

Thank you for the explanation! As I said to Marek R earlier, I'm not going to look at the code you provided just yet. I'm going to see if I can digest the concepts you're talking about and get it into code myself. If I'm still stuck, I'll reference your code for a bailout. Thank you! John

For what it's worth, I knew the string concatenation represented a lot of work, but at that point in my journey I couldn't think of another way to check whether I had visited a certain permutation before, without storing its visual representation.
